# Modem does not return my program's echo request

Tags: c++, serial-port

1. Typing `AT` + `[Enter]` on PuTTY to my modem's COM3 port gives me `OK` as a response.
2. I used my CHAR-sending-and-recieving program to analyze PuTTY's output when it sends data.
3. `AT`+`[Enter]` makes PuTTY send a `AT\r` through a port.

(`\r` meaning a carriage return with an ASCII value of 13.)

4. I used my program to send the same stream of CHARs to the COM3 port.
5. Modem didn't respond with `OK`. It doesn't send anything as a response to my program at all. Ever. Not even `ERROR` messages.
6. (I tested my program, and it can recieve data *right after* sending data of its own, so unlikely it didn't catch the `OK` in time, since I also requested longer strings as a response - strings that would be hard to miss.)
7. (It has no problems communicating through ports with another program and with PuTTY.)

What is the cause for this? How can I recieve modem's `OK` response?

(I also tested strings ending with `\n`, `\r\n` and `\n\r` like I was advised, just in case. Didn't work.)

**CODE (ports COM8 and COM9 are connected btw):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;



bool WriteComPort(LPCTSTR portSpecifier, LPCTSTR data) ;
int ReadByte(LPCTSTR portSpecifier) ;
void Transciever( LPCTSTR portSpecifier ) ;


int main ()
{
    LPCTSTR portSpecifier = "" ;
    string temp = "" ;

    do
    {
        cout << "\nCOM8 or COM9 or COM3? " ;
        getline(cin,temp) ;
        if( temp == "COM8" || temp == "COM9" || temp == "COM3" ) portSpecifier = temp.c_str() ;

    } while( temp != "COM8" && temp != "COM9" && temp != "COM3" ) ;

    Transciever(portSpecifier) ;



    cout << "[Program terminated.]\n" ;

    cin.get() ;
    return 0 ;
}



void Transciever(LPCTSTR portSpecifier )
{
    string text ;
    LPCSTR data ;
    bool writeSuccess = true ;
    char output ;

    do
    {
        if( _kbhit() )
        {
            text = _getch() ;
            data =  text.c_str() ;

            writeSuccess = WriteComPort(portSpecifier,data) ;

            if(!writeSuccess) cout << "[Sending error.]\n" ;
            else
            {
                cout << text ;
            }
        }

        output = (char) ReadByte(portSpecifier) ;
        if( output != '_' )
        {
            cout << output ;

            if( output == '=' )
            {
                data =  "*" ;
                writeSuccess = WriteComPort(portSpecifier,data) ;

                if(!writeSuccess) cout << "\n[    FAIL: Sending a * autoresponse to = ]\n" ;
                             else cout << "\n[ SUCCESS: Sending a * autoresponse to = ]\n" ;
            }
        }

    } while( text != "#" && output != '#' ) ;
}



bool WriteComPort(LPCTSTR portSpecifier, LPCTSTR data)
{
    DCB dcb;
    DWORD       bytesWritten;

    HANDLE hPort = CreateFile( portSpecifier,
                               GENERIC_WRITE,
                               0,
                               NULL,
                               OPEN_EXISTING,
                               0,
                               NULL );

       if (!GetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
       {
           cout << "Failed getting " << portSpecifier << " port's state.\n" ;
           return       false;
       }

       dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;          //9600 Baud
       dcb.ByteSize = 7;                 //7 data bits
       dcb.Parity = TRUE;
       dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;        //1 stop

       if (!SetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
       {
           cout << "[Failed setting " << portSpecifier << "'s state.]\n" ;
           return false ;
       }

       int bytesToWrite = 1 ;

       bool retVal = WriteFile(hPort,data,bytesToWrite,&bytesWritten,NULL);

       CloseHandle(hPort); //close the handle

       return  retVal;
}



int ReadByte(LPCTSTR portSpecifier)
{
    DCB dcb;
    int retVal;
    BYTE Byte = '_' ;
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
    HANDLE hPort = CreateFile
    (
        portSpecifier,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL
    );
    if (!GetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
    {
        cout << "\n[GetCommState FAIL]\n" ;
        return '_' ;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;

    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hPort, &timeouts))
    {
        cout << "\n[SetCommTimeouts FAIL]\n" ;
        return '_' ;
    }

    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600; //9600 Baud
    dcb.ByteSize = 7; //7 data bits
    dcb.Parity = TRUE; //parity
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop

    if (!SetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
    {
        cout << "\n[SetCommState FAIL]\n" ;
        return '_' ;
    }

    if (!SetCommMask (hPort, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR) )
    {
        cout << "\n[SetCommMask FAIL]\n" ;
        return '_' ;
    }

    if( !ReadFile (hPort, &Byte, 1, &dwBytesTransferred, 0) )
    {
        cout << "\n[ReadFile FAIL]\n" ;
        return '_' ;
    }

    retVal = Byte;
    if (!CloseHandle(hPort))
    {
        cout << "\n[CloseHandle FAIL]\n" ;
        return '_' ;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

.

**Also an alternative version of ReadByte, which reads many bytes at once:**

```
string ReadByte(LPCTSTR portSpecifier)
{
    DCB dcb;
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
    HANDLE hPort = CreateFile
    (
        portSpecifier,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL
    );
    if (!GetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
    {
        cout << "\n[ReadByte: GetCommState FAIL]\n" ;
        return "-1" ;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;

    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hPort, &timeouts))
    {
        cout << "\n[ReadByte: SetCommTimeouts FAIL]\n" ;
        return "-1" ;
    }

    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600; //9600 Baud
    dcb.ByteSize = 7; //7 data bits
    dcb.Parity = EVENPARITY; //parity
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop

    if (!SetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
    {
        cout << "\n[ReadByte: SetCommState FAIL]\n" ;
        return "-1" ;
    }

    if (!SetCommMask (hPort, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR) )
    {
        cout << "\n[ReadByte: SetCommMask FAIL]\n" ;
        return "-1" ;
    }

    const int bytesToRead = 30 ;
    char messageRecieved[bytesToRead+1] = {0};
    //&Byte

    if( !ReadFile (hPort, &messageRecieved, bytesToRead, &dwBytesTransferred, 0) )
    {
        cout << "\n[ReadByte: ReadFile FAIL]\n" ;
        return "-1" ;
    }



    if (!CloseHandle(hPort))
    {
        cout << "\n[ReadByte: CloseHandle FAIL]\n" ;
        return "-1" ;
    }

    if( dwBytesTransferred == bytesToRead )
    {
        cout << "\n[ReadByte: possible that the message was cut off at the end." ;
    }

    return string(messageRecieved) ;
}
```

Comment: Do *not* close the port immediately after writing something, it takes time to get the data transmitted to the modem.  Open the port when your program starts, don't close it until it ends.  Never is fine too.  Not initializing the handshaking in the DCB is a bug as well.